# Is there a way of removing every character before a specific character and at the same time add a prefix?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula extracting data from another cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(ISBLANK(D10),REGEXMATCH(D10, "\*$"),REGEXMATCH(D10,"RECYCLE.BIN"),REGEXMATCH(D10,"System Volume Information")),,RIGHT(D10,LEN(D10)-(FIND("\",D10)+0))))
```

It's there a way of incorporate this next section of a formula together with "RIGHT"? So it will remove everything before the backslash "" and also the add "     └─     " prefix?

```
"     └─     " & D10
```

I've tried so many different things like adding this part at the end:

```
RIGHT(D10,LEN(D10)-(FIND("\",D10)+0)+("     └─     " & D10))
```

I expect to have the prefix added after characters are removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula should produce the behavior you desire (replacing all characters before a backslash in cell D10 with     `└─`    ).

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D10,".*\\","     └─     ")
```

Incorporating the rest of your formula directly as written:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(ISBLANK(D10),REGEXMATCH(D10, "\*$"),REGEXMATCH(D10,"RECYCLE.BIN"),REGEXMATCH(D10,"System Volume Information")),,REGEXREPLACE(D10,".*\\","     └─     ")))
```

As an alternative that improves efficiency:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(D10,"\*$|RECYCLE.BIN|System Volume Information|^$"),,REGEXREPLACE(D10,".*\\"," └─ "))
```

Functions Used:

- [=REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)
- [=ARRAYFORMUlA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [=ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en)
- [=IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [=OR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en)
- [=REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much Sebastian.